# Different imagine quality and positioning among different browsers

Tags: google-maps-api-3, tile, geopositioning

I noticed an apparent problem of positioning on Google Maps and comparing result among different browsers cannot explain the behavior.

I took the coordinates of a point with Chrome. I entered the same coordinates on IE (both in numeric decimal notation and latitude / longitude) and the positioning of the point is shifted by a few tenths of meters together with the fact that the image (tile) is different, photographed in a different moment (see the shadows) and quality is significantly worse with IE.

Firefox behaves like Chrome, Safari behaves like IE.

Finally, if you use the Google API v.3 behavior is always as with IE / Safari regardless of the browser used.

Is there an explanation for this difference in behavior? Is there a way to have the same positioning and image quality as Chrome/Firefox using Google Maps API?

Thanks a lot.

Map with Google Maps on Chrome
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8x8Ni0UO0QeS2t3X1NXVjF1Vjg/view?usp=sharing

Map with Google Maps and IE
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8x8Ni0UO0QeVkZocHA1ZEdoV3c/view?usp=sharing